# Как решить такую задачу в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 8.0.29

У меня есть подписка:

```
id, value, days
```

Также, есть ордер:

```
id, subscriptionId, date
```

Одна подписка может иметь несколько ордеров. Например, я купил ее в июне, потом еще раз в августе.

Подписка считается активной, если она содержит ордер, что был создан не менее 30 дней назад.

Выбрать активные подписки у меня получилось. Просто выбираю те, где есть ордеры, что подходят под условие.

**Проблема с тем, что не могу выбрать только не активные подписки.**

Конструктор: [тык.](https://dbfiddle.uk/W4VSFT2C)

## UPDATE

subscription

```sql
CREATE TABLE subscription (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value INT
);
```

orders

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subscriptionId INT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (subscriptionId) REFERENCES subscription (id)
)
```

данные

```sql
INSERT INTO
    `subscription` (`id`, `value` )
VALUES
    (1, 10);
INSERT INTO
    `orders` (`subscriptionId`, `date` )
VALUES
    (1, "2022-10-07 12:06:38"),
    (1, "2021-10-07 12:06:38");
```

Мое решение:

```sql
            WITH active (activeId) AS (
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT(subscriptionId) AS 'activeId'
                FROM
                    subscription_order
                WHERE
                    subscription_order.createdAt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `subscription`.`days` DAY)
            ),
            notActive (notActiveId) AS (
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT(subscriptionId) AS 'notActiveId'
                FROM
                    subscription_order
                WHERE
                    subscription_order.createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `subscription`.`days` DAY)
            )
            SELECT
                notActiveId AS 'subscriptionId'
            FROM
                active
                RIGHT JOIN notActive ON active.activeId = notActive.notActiveId
            WHERE
                active.activeId IS NULL
```

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Akina, решил это так https://pastebin.com/d2x8JLqb. А что, можно проще?

Comment: А это зависит от того, что вы считаете неактивными. Исходя из того запроса, что написали вы, могу предположить что под ними вы понимаете такие подписки, по которым были ордера, но более 30 дней назад. В вопросе про необходимость наличия хотя бы одного ордера ничего не сказано. Если считать что ордер должен быть, то `select subscriptionId from subscription_order group by subscriptionId having max(createdAt) < now() - interval 1 day` join добавить по вкусу. Если же проверить и на полное отсутствие ордеров, то учесть тут еще null